# Is there any unsupervised scoring algorithm for scoring pre-identified anomalies in time series?

Tags: time-series, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I am having a tricky time determining an unsupervised scoring algorithm for pre-identified anomalies in timeseries. Take this class:

```
{
  float timestamp; 
  int value; 
  Boolean is_anomaly; 
  float predicted;
}
```

The anomaly_score is score from 0 to 100. The algorithm should be online i.e. when scoring an anomaly at timestamp t, the
algorithm should have access to only data w/ corresponding timestamp less than or equal
to t. Thanks a lot, ...

Comment: What does it mean that anomalies are "pre-identified" ?

Comment: You say "anomaly_score", but there is no such field in your class?